# Вынесение элемента управления

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как вынести элемент управления WPF, например Grid, из основного xaml файла в отдельный. Затем, как его подключить в основном xaml файле?
Буду очень благодарен, если приведете пример с xaml.

Comment: Через UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляете свой элемент управления:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем "кладете" в него свой Grid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GM_Assistant.Windows.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

После - добавляете пространство имен с вашим контролом в основной файл и используете его:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFProject1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WPFProject1.UserControls"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <uc:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```